# Ruby (not Rails) on IIS 7 via FastCGI

Tags: ruby, iis-7, iis-7.5, fastcgi

Hopefully this is a simple one. I want to run Ruby on IIS 7+ as I would PHP, Perl, Python, etc. (that is to set a handler mapping to `.rb` files).

Every time I Google for it I get Rails. But I don't want to run Rails, I would just like to run straight Ruby.

I know I'll to set up my headers and all sorts of other stuff, since, unlike PHP, Ruby isn't technically native to the web.

I'm looking for a manual installation for this, not something automated with an executable.

My reason for needing this is simply for learning.

Any answers would be very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: You would set it up as a CGI just like any other cgi.  This blog post has details that may help: http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/04/04/how-to-run-a-cgi-program-under-iis-7-0-or-iis-7-5.aspx

Comment: i tried that and was getting 500 errors :(

Comment: You might list some errors, to help define the path you are taking.

Comment: they're unknown errors, it just spits out a 500 and said the application stopped working.

Comment: Oh, you were getting a 500 Unknown Command Error.  Do you have the virtual directory setup?  Ruby is installed, the path to the executable is known and allowed?

Comment: i actually did a few things, the main one a tried was the same way that php is set, ie running a handler on the ruby.exe for .rb files. i never used any virtual directories before im only looking to parse ruby files

Comment: I wouldn't worry about Ruby being *"less native"* to the internet than PHP etc. Ruby is fast: very fast. And it is more than able to access STDIN and the environment variables as is required for CGI. You should start by getting your Ruby app running. Printing a `text/plain` header and a line of text should be enough.

Comment: im not worried about it being less native by any means actually! :)
but this doesnt really answer my question :(